# Nestable tree does not work in a modal ui- bootstrap using the < script> < / script>

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I try to display a tree in a modal Nestable ui- bootstrap , but select - + does not will pop up and does not work when injected into the  between the   to ui modal -bootstrap
( jquery.nestable.js ) how I can solve this problem !

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="dd" id="nestable">
        <ol class="dd-list">
            <li class="dd-item" class="dd-item" data-id="1">
                <div class="dd-handle">Entretien</div>
                <ol class="dd-list">
                    <li class="dd-item" data-id="1">
                        <div class="dd-handle"  ng-click="setSelectedSegment(valSegment)">Lessives</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dd-item" data-id="1">
                        <div class="dd-handle"  ng-click="setSelectedSegment(valSegment)">FFI</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dd-item" data-id="1"> <div class="dd-handle"  ng-click="setSelectedSegment(valSegment)">HDW</div></li>
                    <li class="dd-item" data-id="1"> <div class="dd-handle"  ng-click="setSelectedSegment(valSegment)">ADW</div></li>
                    <li class="dd-item" data-id="1"> <div class="dd-handle"  ng-click="setSelectedSegment(valSegment)">Produits WC</div></li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</script>
<button  class="safe btn btn-default btn-white btn-segmentation" ng-click="open()">{{ selectedTree ? selectedTree : 'Segmentation' }}</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have seen most of the time is that when events are not firing correctly in a modal window, it's because the modal is creating elements that needed to be present on `pageload` in order to be bound correctly. An easy way to fix would be to fire nestable.js when the modal is triggered, rather than on the initial page load. Of course, many ways to solve this but this tends to be a fairly quick and easy fix.

```
$('#modal-ID').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('.dd').nestable();
})
```

Comment: thank you Joe, the nestable work perfectly but ng-click dont work if i add this  $('#modal-ID').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('.dd').nestable();
})  to my directive !

Comment: Take a look at this page: http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/displaying-a-modal-dialog.html